# Не могу понять, что означает "-> float" в Python

Tags: python

Вот сам код на Python, помогите разобраться, что означает -> float: (задача стоит переписать данный код на C++)

```
mod = 2 ** 31 - 1

a, b = map(int, input("Insert two nums:").split(" "))


def long_pow(x: float, power: int) -> float:
  if power == 1:
    return x
  if power % 2 == 0:
    temp = long_pow(x, power / 2)
    return temp ** 2 % mod
  else:
    return long_pow(x, power - 1) * x % mod


print(a * long_pow(b, mod - 2) % mod)
```

Comment: Хм, странно, оно тут означает ровно то же, что и в с++ - тип возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Извините, я новичок и мой друг, который совсем не разбирается попросил меня помочь, если смогу, а я заинтересовался и хочу понять

Comment: А не могли бы назвать тему, связанную с этим -> float?

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Comment: Могу я Вас спросить, почему в Python при использовании % (mod) с нецелым числом всё работает, а в C++ выдает ошибку?

Comment: И там, и там, в этом случае следует использовать библиотечную функцию `fmod`.

Answer (score 0):

Тип возвращаемой переменной. Но это опционально. Поищите "python typing".